# Condition or Proof: Minimizer of one function is maximizing another function

Tags: analysis, optimization, numerical-methods, derivatives, calculus-of-variations

I have two real functions $f(X),g(X)$ where the argument $X$ is a real matrix. The solution $X^*$ for the problem of minimizing $f$ is ending up maximizing $g$ as well. I am looking for a way to prove or at least understand the condition/reasoning behind why this is happening for these two functions.

$f(X)=Tr(X^TAX)-Tr(X^TBX)$ and $g(X)=\frac{Tr(X^TBX)}{Tr(X^Th(X)X)}$ and

$h(X)=diag(XX^T\mathbb{1})-XX^T$. $A$ and $B$ are p.s.d matrices.

$B$ is a matrix that does not depend on $X$.

Coming to $A$, this is what I do, I first set $A=h(X)$ for some chosen $X$ and then I keep that matrix constant, in the optimization of $f(.)$, that is it is only optimized on the $X$ terms other than $A$. Let me know if you need more detail/clarification on how I use $A$ in this optimization.

Comment: You have given very little information. If $g=f$ then it is obvious why this will occur. If you want a meaningful answer, you need to elaborate.

Comment: @copper.hat Added more details on the functions

Comment: A brief glance would suggest that this is coincidental, since $f$ depends on $A,B$, whereas $g$ depends on $B$ only. Both $f,g$ are homogeneous of degree 2, so either the maximum is zero, or it is unbounded above.

Comment: @copper.hat I made a gross error while typing the question. I apologize. The observation is that the minimizer (not maximizer) of $f(.)$ is ending up maximizing $g(.)$. Can you look at this version instead? I have corrected it and I also inverted the previous definition of $g(.)$. I can see that minimizing the second term in $f(.)$ with the negative sign can maximize the numerator in $g(.)$. Also $f(.)$ is a sum of a convex and a concave function.

Comment: @copper.hat I made a gross error while typing the question. I apologize. The observation is that the minimizer (not maximizer) of $f(.)$ is ending up maximizing $g(.)$. Can you look at this version instead? I have corrected it and I also inverted the previous definition of $g(.)$. I can see that minimizing the second term in $f(.)$ with the negative sign can maximize the numerator in $g(.)$. Also f(.) is a sum of a convex and a concave function. My doubts are with the denominator of $g(.)$ and on the original question of how to prove that minimizing $f(.)$ can maximize $g(.)$.

Comment: Same basic comment. $f(\lambda X) = \lambda^2 f(X)$ and $g(\lambda X) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} g(X)$, so the $\sup, \inf$ are either $0$ or $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @copper.hat The function $g(.)$ has its range $0$ and $1$- closed interval. Also, as $f(\lambda X)$ increases with increase in $\lambda$ and $g(.)$ decreases- why do you say, 'coincidental' in a comment? Is it not rigorous enough a statement that minimizing one would maximize the other? Anything that is missing here-that would make this invalid in some cases? Also, as $g(.)$ is non-convex, would this inverse relation exist if i ordered the local minimas of $g(.)$ and compared the sorted order w.r.t $f(.)$ would they perfectly be of a reverse order?

Comment: First, I am not sure what you mean by $diag(...)$ above, so I'm not sure if I am correct about $g$, that is, I presumed $h(\lambda X) = \lambda^2 h(X)$. Second, (and assuming I am correct about $h$) the extreme values of $f,g$ are $0, \pm \infty$, so depending on the choice of $A,B$ (this is what I meant by coincidental) the extreme values of $f,g$ may match.

Comment: @copper.hat Interesting. First- $diag(.)$ is a diagonal matrix formed with the diagonal elements being the diagonal elements of the matrix in the placeholder $(⋅)$. You are right that it seems like $λ$ gets squared. Now, I can confirm that $B$ is a matrix that does 'not' depend on $X$. Now, to start with, if I said, $A=h(X)$, then is it a provable enough statement by reasoning with the $λ$ argument that minimizing one would always maximize the other? Also, I appended the question on how I define and use $A$ in the optimization process. Just read the last three lines of the question for info.

Comment: Hmm, your last comment and the fact that $A$ is not constant has completely thrown me. I'm not sure I can be of assistance here.

Comment: @copper.hat Just to clarify- $A$ is kept constant in the optimization process, that is- it is not optimized on $A$. But- it is true that a random $X=R$ is chosen initially and then $A$ is made the result of a matrix valued function h(X=R) and then it is fixed constantly and the optimization is only run on the $X$ terms other than $A$ which are the variables-but $A$ is no longer a function and made constant.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Answered before new details were added. I'll revisit this.

This will be true generically when $g$ is a monotonic transformation of $f$ (transformation by a strictly increasing function). When this is the case: $g(x)\geq g(\tilde{x})\Leftrightarrow f(x)\geq f(\tilde{x}) $

Since $f(x^*)\geq f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain, $g(x^*)\geq g(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain as well.

Comment: How is this relevant to the OP's question? It is not at all clear to me that $g$ is a monotonic transformation of $f$?